# How to remove empty items in a list box?

Tags: c#, listbox, listboxitem, listboxitems

I have a `Listbox` called `TeachersList` I populate it with string values from a database. Now I want to remove any thing that was imported as empty. When the list loads it gives blank items and I don't want this. I tried using a for loop but it doesn't work.
this what I used

```
int CountEmptyValues = TeachersList.Items.Count;
for (int i = CountEmptyValues - 1; i >= 0; i--)        
    if (TeachersList.Items[i].ToString() == " ")
    {
        TeachersList.Items.RemoveAt(i);
    }
```

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

And here is how I added items from the database into the listbox

```
                MySqlConnection TeachersDB = new MySqlConnection();
                string SchoolsDbString = TeachersDB.ConnectionString = @"server=localhost;Port=3306; user id=root; password=test; database=" + Globals.DBChosen;
                MySqlDataAdapter SubjectsAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select " + SearchByField.Text + " From users", TeachersDB);
                DataSet Dataset = new DataSet();
                TeachersDB.Open(); 

                SubjectsAdapter.Fill(Dataset); 
                TeachersList.DataSource = Dataset.Tables[0];
                TeachersList.DisplayMember = SearchByField.Text;
```

Comment: My question is first of all why'd you want to add `Empty` values? Why can't you filter and add?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel well I don't really want to add empty values. How can I filter them? I just used a simple import code. but I didn't go through any filtering process. How is that possible?

Comment: Show me the adding code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the table using `Linq` easily, we create a `DataView` out of it and set the `DataView` as DataSource. You're done.

```
string searchBy = SearchByField.Text;
TeachersList.DataSource = Dataset.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Field<string>(searchBy))).AsDataView();
TeachersList.ValueMember = searchBy;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @MuhandJumah You can alternatively filter the string using where condition from sql. I suppose that would be more efficient.

Comment: hmm this makes sense to use as well. That's a good one to use, it didn't cross my mind hehe